# Should my HP Pavilion dv6000 operate w/o battery pack while using electrical plug-in? Mine won't

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power

While using my computer, it shut down, and I cannot get it to turn back on. I have tried removing the battery to see if the computer would work without it, but it did not. The light is on where the power cord plugs into the computer. I Put battery in, the battery light on, I try powering up, all the lights come on, but after only 5 seconds it dies, Help.

Comment: Before it shut down, did you see any warnings that the battery was running low?

Comment: @Connor W: Can you visit chat sometime when I'm around? @studiohack me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have had no dealings with your particular model but my Dell and HP Elitebook both work with the battery removed. It may be that your power supply is not giving out sufficient volts, resulting in your battery discharging. That would explain why the battery only works for a moment and why it won't work with just the power supply plugged in. If it is out of warranty, take it to a computer repair shop (or the shop where you bought it) and ask them to try a different power supply with it.

Answer (score 1):

The HP dv6000 series is prone to many failures, most are motherboard related, it is also part if an Nvidia settlement

http://www.nvidiasettlement.com/affectedmodels.html

.

There is also a high quality reputable repair service for the DV line of Notebooks

http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=260674058980

> Weird colored screen (grey, green, red etc.
>
> Scrambled or pixelated screen.
>
> Divided split screen (2 screens up to 12 split screens).
>
> Screen black however backlit.
>
> Screen black with no backlight however blue lights come on the quickplay panel.
>
> Turns on then shuts off immediatly.
>
> Turns on and beeps 3 times (1 long and 2 short).
>
> Turns on, black screen and keeps restarting by itself.
>
> White or grey screen sometimes with horizontal lines.
>
> Press power button and nothing happens what so ever (seems dead) (mostly on DV2000 models).
>
> Intel models boot to backlight but no screen.
>
> Cant load Nvidia driver, can only run in VGA mode.
>
> Screen works but no WiFi (does not show up in device manager).
>
> and much more, if you don't see your symptom on this list, email me

Disclaimer, I have no affiliation with this service, all I know is their rating is very high and have recommended it to many others which reported high satisfaction of the repair service they received.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be related to motherboard (graphic card specifically), looking at your condition seems that your laptop ran hot in last days and finally damaged the graphic card connection to the board. If you have some technical skills related to hardware, you may heat treat the motherboard for the graphic card. If you don't understand these terms you may better consult a professional repair shop.

1. The laptop must work with battery removed (almost all models)
2. Before you test that you may want to hard start. (remove the battery->remove the power cable ->hold on the power button for few seconds-> connect the power cable -> power on the laptop) if it does not help.
3. Try to start it on safe mode, after the power button press the f8 key periodically 1 sec interval. If this as well does not help, see if you can go to the BIOS settings must be f2 for HP after you hit power button.
4. Not able to start from all these go ahead with heat treatment.

Comment: Later on discovered it was a old thread, still kept it as it may help some others.

Comment: This post is absurd.  There is no basis to conclude that the graphics card is the problem or to recommend "heat treating" the motherboard.